# Why there is a different coercion behaviour between these two use of apply & lapply

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I needed to create a list out of a data.frame in a row-by-row shape for later conversion to JSON.

I was surprised to see a different behaviour between apply and lapply:

- apply coerces all to character
- lapply preserves the datatype (as I wanted)

This is an example:

```
df_ = data.frame( Month = month.abb[1:5],
A=rnorm(5, mean = 5, sd = 4),
B=rnorm(5, mean = 5, sd = 4),
C=rnorm(5, mean = 5, sd = 4),
D=rnorm(5, mean = 5, sd = 4),
E=rnorm(5, mean = 5, sd = 4), stringsAsFactors=F)


df1_ <- lapply(1:nrow(df_), function(i) {l_ <- as.list(df_[i, ])
    return(l_)})

df2_ <- apply(df_,1, as.list)

df1_[[1]]
$Month
[1] "Jan"

$A
[1] 8.235366

$B
[1] -0.2163872

$C
[1] 10.75159

$D
[1] 5.401502

$E
[1] 7.175394

df2_[[1]]
$Month
[1] "Jan"

$A
[1] "8.2353656"

$B
[1] "-0.2163872"

$C
[1] "10.751592"

$D
[1] " 5.4015020"

$E
[1] " 7.175394"
```

As far as I can tell they appear identical, but apply has coerced all numeric to character, while lapply has preserved them as numeric.

I would like to have an understanding of why this happens, to avoid this pitfall in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` takes `matrix` arguments. `data.frame`s will be coerced to `matrix` before anything else is done. Hence the conversion of everything to the same type (`character`).

`lapply` takes `list` arguments. Therefore it coerces the `data.frame` to a `list` and does not have to convert the arguments.